# What materials are required to craft a full set of exotic armour?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I want to make a full set of exotic "medium" (ie: leatherworking) armour but haven't bought any of the recipes for the insignias yet. In this instance I'm wanting the Precision and Condition Damage stats on my gear so I'm probably going to go with Rampager's Insignias.

Before I set out farming for materials, how many of each material will I need to craft a full set of exotic armour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The materials you will then need to make a piece of gear for each slot are listed below, along with the rare crafting materials required to make each type of armour (light, medium or heavy) and the materials required to make each type of insignia;

### Primary Crafting Materials

The type of crafting material you use depends on the type of armour you are creating;

- For *light* and *medium* armours it is Cured Hardened Leather Square
- For *heavy* armours it is Orichalcum Ingot

### Crafting Components

**Boots**

- 1x Insignia
- 4x Primary Crafting Material
- 1x Spool of Gossamer Thread

**Gloves**

- 1x Bolt of Gossamer
- 1x Insignia
- 2x Primary Crafting Material
- 1x Spool of Gossamer Thread

**Helmet**

- 2x Bolt of Gossamer
- 1x Insignia
- 1x Primary Crafting Material
- 1x Spool of Gossamer Thread

**Coat**

- 1x Bolt of Gossamer
- 1x Insignia
- 5x Primary Crafting Material
- 3x Spool of Gossamer Thread

**Shoulders**

- 1x Bolt of Gossamer
- 1x Insignia
- 2x Primary Crafting Material
- 1x Spool of Gossamer Thread

**Legs**

- 1x Bolt of Gossamer
- 1x Insignia
- 4x Primary Crafting Material
- 3x Spool of Gossamer Thread

### Insignias

Insignia recipes can be purchased from your crafting discipline trainer, these recipes are exotic quality and cost 896 karma to purchase. Each insignia requires the following materials, plus one additional material as detailed below;

- 5x Bolt of Gossamer
- 20x Spool of Gossamer Thread
- 5x Glob of Ectoplasm

**Apothecary's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 30x Karka Shell

**Berserker's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Vial of Powerful Blood

**Carrion Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Ancient Bone

**Cleric's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Elaborate Totem

**Explorer's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Vicious Claw

**Knight's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Armored Scale

**Rampager's Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Powerful Venom Sac

**Valkyrie Intricate Gossamer Insignia**

- 5x Vicious Fang

### The total materials you require

Keeping in mind that some of these materials are creating by refining materials you find on enemies, it is possible to break this down further as follows;

- 40x Hardened Leather Section = 20x Cured Hardened Leather Square
- 72x Gossamer Scrap = 36x Bolt of Gossamer

Based on making *medium* armour from leatherworking, using *Rampager's Intricate Gossamer Insignias*, the total materials that you would require to make a full set of exotic gear are as follows;

- 30x Powerful Venom Sac
- 30x Glob of Ectoplasm
- 36x Bolt of Gossamer
- 130x Spool of Gossamer Thread
- 20x Cured Hardened Leather Square

This will make you exotic Boots, Coat, Gloves, Helm, Legs, and Shoulders.

Comment: I think you are missing the leather above. You have bolts of gossamer, but no hardened leather squares. I'd also consider breaking bolts / squares into scraps / leather, since those are the items you're likely to actually *find*.

Comment: @RavenDreamer check under 'Rare Crafting Materials' section, all crafting disciplines use Gossamer Thread/Bolts, but the rest is clarified under its own section as it differs depending on if you're making light/medium/heavy armour

Comment: Oh. I see. That's highly unintuitive.

Comment: @RavenDreamer moved the *rare crafting materials* section to the top to make it more visible!